# Please change the "0 Answers" style on SuperUser

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, color

The "0 Answers" style on SuperUser looks horrid/out of place.

You know the one I'm talking about, the big burgundy box of badness.

[image: one is not really the loneliest number, nor blue the saddest color]

Comment: Now it's pink. Need a new alliteration...

Comment: putrid pink prose?

Comment: Image can't be served over https, can you please re-upload? (can't suggest edits here.) [source](http://crowdcrafting.org/project/sehttpimagescleanup/task/1705773).

Comment: Fixed the image

Answer (score 13):

It's good that it's noticeable, but bad that it doesn't appear to fit well with the rest of the site. I'd prefer to see a lighter shade used, and used on the text and border rather than the background.

[image: Oh, and round corners like the tags - then it'll only look like crap on IE...]

Comment: I really like this design.

Comment: Agreed, this is very nice.

Comment: This is very nice.

Answer (score 8):

I disagree! I think questions without answers **should** look out of place. It's a community focused on asking and answering questions - no answers strikes me as something that should stand out.

Comment: Where is the community decision here?

Comment: It's ugly as sin, *and that's a good thing* !

Comment: -I- disagree - you may not! I'd rather informative than ugly, I think.

Answer (score 2):

On my monitor, it doesn't look black, it looks like a *really* deep burgundy.

Regardless, I think it could be made to stand out without clashing.  I'd suggest trying something in the yellows.

Comment: hmm... burgundy works.  As long as you keep the alliteration ;)

Answer (score 1):

Agreed:  It's way too dark!  Change the value (as in HSV) on the burgundy to be a little lighter.

Comment: Or give it a white background and use the dark burgundy for the fore-color.

Comment: Yes, I like that idea even better.  I'd also swap the answer/unanswered colors:  I think it makes more sense to use yellow  for "unanswered" questions and green for "answered".